# How to download media content from android app after paying in-app purchase?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am developing an android app which offers in-app purchases. The content I want to sell is media files like images and audio files. I would like to implement a mechanism to download those files from an external server (maybe Google App Engine could be helpful) after the user has paid for a file.

My concerns are:

1. I want to make the mechanism independent of the amount of files I want to sell. This means that adding new content to the google play console should not require any update of my app.
2. How to protect any kind of URL on the device side that gives any clue about where the content is hosted?

Has anyone done something similar already? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Note - my experience is with a previous version of Google's IAP.  I assume what I say below still works but have yet to upgrade my app.

1) Have your application contact your server for the list of products for sale.  Note that your play account will have to contain an entry for each element offered in order to give pricing and description information.

2) You cannot protect the URL.  What you can do is protect the content.  As part of the request to get the information, you should pass receipt information that can be verified at the server (see Google docs) before allowing access.   Might also want to think about things like nonces and other security techniques to prevent replays.